# MongoDB database design with addresses

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to figure out how to design my database in terms of addresses. For example, I have real estate agents who would be inputting property information. I'm using MongoDB and is the best approach separating out by city, state, zip and having id's in each of these collections that point to the property id? Or would i just include it in the property collection itself.

if i'm not mistaken with MySQL you would separate it out, but i'm not sure of the best approach with non-relational databases.

Also, wouldn't updating be horrendous in the controller? I'm using a MEAN stack.

I've drawn out some possibilities if anybody has any thoughts.[adding to the property collection itself](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5L7N.jpg)

[separate out the address, city, state etc as separate collections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qxaD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are right SQL would be as you drew it but in non relational db goal is to have almost all info in one document. Some data replication is not an issue as memory nowdays is cheap (Processing power is expensive more or less). So, if you keep everything in one place you only need single query to retrieve all info about property plus many more benefits.

To answer your question your approach is a big no in MongoDb. You will produce yourself a living nightmare as joins in mongo are "almost nonexistant".

Special case is if your addresses will be repeated a lot. Then you can make Addresses collection and Properties collection and have address id in property.

You can find more info on modeling relations here:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

Enjoy your day!

EDIT: ahh I didn't see. Go for picture one =)